# proguard syntax meaning of * and **

Tags: android, proguard

I found below two cases:

```
-keep class com.android.ons.** {*;}
-keep class com.android.ons.* {*;}
```

One is using ** but another one is using *. what's the difference?

Answer (score 0):

From the proguard [manual](https://www.guardsquare.com/manual/refcard):

> Types in classname, annotationtype, returntype, and argumenttype can contain wildcards: '?' for a single character, '*' for any number of characters (but not the package separator), '**' for any number of (any) characters, '%' for any primitive type, '***' for any type, '...' for any number of arguments, and '<n>' for the n'th matched wildcard in the same option.

The single asterisk doesn't match the package separator, `.`, that version of the `-keep` wouldn't keep classes in packages nested within `com.android.ons`. So, if there was a package named `com.android.ons.somepackage`, classes within that package would not be kept if you only had the single asterisk version.

The double asterisk version matches the package separator, so that would keep any classes in the top-level `com.android.ons` package **and** any packages nested within `com.android.ons`, so any class in `com.android.ons.somepackage` would also be kept.

It is therefore redundant to specify the single asterisk version as well as the double asterisk version.